# Selecting specific posts with an if statement in a counted loop

Tags: php, loops, count

I'm currently counting the posts in the loop...

```
<?php $count = 0; ?>
<?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php $count++; ?>
    <?php include(locate_template('content.php')); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

But need to select specific posts programmatically in an `if` statement.

The post count I need to select is 1, 4, 5, 8, 9, 12, 13 etc (+3+1r) in sequence.

How can I select these posts (without having to manually type the numbers)?

Comment: Use the modulus operator. This is pure php which is off topic here. Voting to move this to SO

Comment: Yes I realise it is PHP - just wondering if there wasn't something specific in Wordpress that could handle this that I was unaware of. Move to SO if necessary.

Comment: No, nothing specific in Wordpress to achieve this. Modulus operator with a normal counter will do the trick :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While technically off topic for WordPress, I think this is something that a good number ueses will enquire about, particularly those that are new to both WordPress and PHP.

As suggested in the comments to your question, you can use a modulus operator to check this, and hopefully this answer will solve your problem.

```
<?php
$count = 0;
/* Start the Loop */
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

    $count++;

    if($count % 4 === 0 || $count % 4 === 1) :
        locate_template('content.php', true);
    endif;

endwhile;
?>
```

As a side note, the `locate_template` function will automatically load the template file with **require_once** (if you set the `$load` parameter), so you don't need to wrap it in `include()`.

I'd recommended that you check if the template exists, and if not fall back on a theme default that will always be there.

Comment: This was exactly what I was after and works perfectly, thanks very much David :)